# Поиск количества одинаковых значений в пяти столбцах mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

У меня есть таблица в mysql состоящая из пяти столбцов. В каждом столбце есть определенные значения. Как можно посчитать количество этих значений во всех пяти столбцах?
База примерно так выглядит

```
id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5
101 | 105 | 101 | 105 | 201
101 | 101 | 104 | 104 | 201
105 | 101 | 101 | 105 | 201
105 | 101 | 104 | 201 | 201
101 | 201 | 101 | 105 | 201
```

Comment: какие считаем, те, которые больше одного раза, всё равно где, больше одного в разных, те которые есть во всех столбцах?

Comment: считать сколько во всех столбцах количество строк со значением 101, сколько во всех столбцах строк с значением 104 и тд, со всеми значениями

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, sum(qty) from
(
select id1 id, count(*) qty from t group by id1
union all
select id2 id, count(*) qty from t group by id2
union all
select id3 id, count(*) qty from t group by id3
union all
select id4 id, count(*) qty from t group by id4
union all
select id5 id, count(*) qty from t group by id5
) X
group by id
```

Comment: Что-то по этому запросу у меня группируется не совсем верно. Я подсчитал вручную на своей базе, самое частое значение у меня встречается 51 раз. А через этот запрос всего 10.

Comment: @Сергей, на твоих данных из вопроса всё [работает](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kiDfqYvgtScJAK6xgtN9Mp/0)… как именно подсчитывал?